# 'Value' of $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

There's a little problem I've been thinking about for a while and can't get an answer.
Consider the following interval: $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ as $n$ goes to infinity.
Would it be equal to $0$ or not??
My reasoning went like this:There are only to possibilities,either it is a point or it is an interval.If it is an interval,then I can rewrite it as: $(0-a,0+a)$ for some positive $a$. But, I would be able to find some $m$ such that $(-a,a)$ is contained in $(-1/m,1/m)$, which is not possible. So it 'has' to be a point. But this contradicts my 'intuition', because $1/n$ is not supposed to be $0$, but some value which becomes really close (i.e. converges) to $0$.

Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT:The reason why I need this is to see whether the infinite union (-1/i,1/i)*R (where * denotes the cartesian product) is an open set of the plane with product topology (and R with standard topology)

Comment: For any $x\neq 0$, can you show that for some $m$, $x$ does not belong to $(-1/m,1/m)$?

Comment: Do you mean the open interval $(-1/n,1/n)$?

Comment: Can you be more precise in what you mean by $(-1/n,1/n)$ as $n$ goes to infinity? What do you mean by the limit of an interval? Think intersections.

Comment: Since an interval is a set, a sequence of intervals has to converge to a set (such as $\{0\}$), not a number (such as $0$).

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough.Yes,I was thinking about the open interval and convergence to the set containing only 0

Comment: @OlivierOloa: According to which definition of convergence? Given that $0\in (-1/m,1/m)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, it obviously should be also element of the limit.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: For sequences $A_1\supset A_2\supset A_3\supset\ldots$, the limit equals the infinite intersection, and only *finite* intersections of open sets are guaranteed to be open. The infinite intersection of open sets can be closed, and this is one example of that.

Comment: @celtschk It makes sense, clarifying the OP question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that what you mean by "$(-1/n,1/n)$ as $n$ goes to infinity" is the intersection of the sequence of open intervals $(-1/n,1/n)$ for $n$ a positive integers, in which case you are trying to find $L$ defined by
$$L = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1/n,1/n)$$
$L$ is the set of all real numbers which are contained in every interval of the form $(-1/n,1/n)$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Clearly $0$ is contained in every interval. If $\epsilon \neq 0$ then $\epsilon \in (-1/n,1/n)$ if and only if $|\epsilon|<1/n$. By the Archimedean property of the real numbers if $|\epsilon| > 0$ then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $1/n<|\epsilon|$. Therefore if $\epsilon \neq 0$ then $\epsilon \notin L$. It follows that $L = \{0\}$.

Note: the definition I've given for $L$ only holds for the sequence of intervals being indexed by positive integers. Otherwise use the definition given by Hetebrij in the comments.

Comment: Is the OP question an infinite intersection?

Comment: It's the only thing I can think of if I'm thinking about the 'limit' of a descending sequence of sets.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \cap_{k=n}^\infty ( - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} )$ in case we add the interval $(-2,-1)$ to the start of our sequence of sets? Which in this case is the same, but in general is different.

Comment: Hmm, true. I just assumed we would start from $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, if it converged to an open interval, it would be on the form of $(-a,a)$, but choosing $n$ "big", you will have that $(-1/n,1/n)$ will be a subset of $(-a,a)$. So, what's wrong? Nothing. The only point contained in every element of the sequence is the zero. Then, you have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1/n,1/n)=\{0\}$$

This is not against the intuition, because as this limit is a sequence of sets $A_n=(-1/n,1/n)$ where $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$, then you could say that it's "strictly decreasing", so the limit of the sets would be the maximal set which is contained in every $A_n$, that is, the set containing only the zero.

You can also say that this limit is an "infinte intersection" of the sets $A_n$, even if it isn't directly defined that way, because you can easily see that for all $n$: $$A_n=\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_j$$ and then the limit of $A_n$ would be an infinite intersection (this happens because of the "strictly decreasing" property of this sequence of sets)

Comment: Is the OP question an infinite intersection?

Comment: Yes it is. I edited my answer to explain better that concept